# Resources about a video decoder implementation in C

Tags: video, implementation, codec, literate-programming

I'm looking for any resources similar to the book "Understanding MP3" by Martin Ruckert, about how to implement a video decoder in C.

In that book the author uses the literate programming to implement a MP3 decoder and explains it line by line. I wonder if a similar resource is available for any popular video formats like MP4.

I'm mostly interested in how a video decoder is implemented. This is not a question about how to write a C program to decode a video file using ffmpeg library.